# Firebase doesn't save full data from object

Tags: angular, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I have a problem with firebase. I create a typical CRUD application in Angular. I have a problem because firebase for some reason does not save the full object - see the details on the screenshots below:

[image: Code from IDE]

[image]

[image: console.log element what I send to firebase]

[image: Firebase Cloud Firestore]

the field "ingredientDetails" is not written to the firebase. Anyone Can help me with it ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Also: Chrome may play tricks on you here when you log an object. To be sure you see exactly what is sent to `addNewList` use `console.log(JSON.stringify(newListToSend))`.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen you are right. JSON.stringify show me element without field "ingrediendDetails" :) Thank you

Comment: Good to hear Damien.  I wrote it up in a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's debugging tools may be playing tricks on you here, as they update objects in the output after it's been printed. Usually this is exactly what you want, but if you're not aware of it, it may lead to false conclusions about the state of the object at the time of logging it.

To be sure you see exactly what is sent to `addNewList` use `console.log(JSON.stringify(newListToSend))` right before that call. Only the data that is logged with this call is passed to `addNewList`, so can make it to the database.